# Flask + sqlalchemy - NameError: global name 'string is not defined

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Cannot figure out why this exception is being thrown only sometimes - maybe one in five attempts.

I have a simple API that accepts a file, stores it, and logs some metadata in a postgres database.

Here's the log:

```
==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016347 2014] [:error] [pid 28259] ERROR:Exception on /api/v1.0/upload [POST]
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016454 2014] [:error] [pid 28259] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016496 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016534 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016576 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016615 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016652 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016689 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016725 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016762 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016798 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016831 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016863 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]   File "__init__.py", line 95, in upload
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016895 2014] [:error] [pid 28259]     width=_file_data['Image width'],
[Fri Oct 03 20:32:02.016939 2014] [:error] [pid 28259] NameError: global name 'string' is not defined
```

In my view:

```
from database import session
from models import SomeInfo

db_entry = SomeInfo(name=f.filename,
                    width=_file_data['Image width'],
                    height=_file_data['Image height'],
                    mime_type=_file_data['MIME type'],
                    duration=_file_data['Duration'],
                    owner=user.username,
                    location=os.path.join(config._upload_directory, f.filename))
```

My model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Sequence, Text, DateTime, ForeignKey
from database import Base, engine

import datetime


class SomeInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_info'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(2048))
    width = Column(String(2048))
    height = Column(String(2048))
    upload_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.today())
    last_modification = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.today())
    SomeMoreStuff

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Sqlalchemy is using postgres as a backend.

Like I said, this only sporadically happens, every fifth post or so to the api.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Lines 85-95 as requested:

```
text = metadata.exportPlaintext()
_file_data = {}
for item in text[1:]:
    _file_data[item.split(':')[0].strip(' -')] = item.split(':')[1]

_file_data['name'] = f.filename
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a variable called `string` somewhere in your code that is only initialized sometimes. I do not believe this is referring to SQLAlchemy's `String` class.

Comment: That's the strange thing - I don't have any variable called string.  I've searched through manually and systematically and can't find anything called 'string'

Comment: Can you post lines ~85-95 from `__init__.py`?

Comment: Thanks, Silas - posted above.

Comment: Your posted line 85-95 don't match your traceback. Where is your `upload()` function that the traceback refers to?